# Can't modify contents of mounted / looped up raw disk image over SSH

Tags: ssh, permissions

On the remote system I run -

```
$ ssh root@my_host echo "    address 192.168.2.150" >> /mnt/loop_mount_point/etc/network/interfaces
-bash: /mnt/loop_mount_point/etc/network/interfaces: No such file or directory
```

However, if I SSH in as root and run the same command, I don't hit any issues.

```
root@my_host:~# echo "    address 192.168.2.150" >> /mnt/loop_mount_point/etc/network/interfaces
root@my_host:~# cat /mnt/loop_mount_point/etc/network/interfaces
...
    address 192.168.2.150
```

Is there a flag I can use on `ssh` or another way around this?

What's more is, if I simply `ls` the directory remotely, you can clearly see its contents -

```
$ ssh root@my_host ls -lash /mnt/loop_mount_point/
total 112K
4.0K drwxr-xr-x 23 root    root    4.0K Oct  2 02:43 .
4.0K drwxr-xr-x  7 brandon brandon 4.0K Oct 26 12:04 ..
4.0K drwxr-xr-x  2 root    root    4.0K Sep 11 02:49 bin
4.0K drwxr-xr-x  3 root    root    4.0K Oct  2 02:44 boot
4.0K drwxr-xr-x  4 root    root    4.0K Sep 12  2018 dev
...
4.0K drwxrwxrwt  7 root    root    4.0K Oct  4 08:36 tmp
4.0K drwxr-xr-x 10 root    root    4.0K Sep 12  2018 usr
4.0K drwxr-xr-x 14 root    root    4.0K Dec  6  2018 var
   0 lrwxrwxrwx  1 root    root      28 Oct  2 02:43 vmlinuz -> boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-1051-aws
   0 lrwxrwxrwx  1 root    root      28 Oct  2 02:43 vmlinuz.old -> boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-1050-aws
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah I figured it out ;)

```
$ ssh root@my_host 'echo "    address 192.168.2.156" >> /mnt/loop_mount_point/etc/network/interfaces'
```

Don't forget those `''`'s.